# Angular2 Undefined Object attribute when using a callback function as Component @Input()

Tags: callback, typescript, angular

Im trying to bind a callback function to a directive, when the event is fired the attribute of the parent component are undefined

app.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {MyComponent} from './my-component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <button (click)="appOnClick('CLICK FROM APP')">BUTTOM OUTSIDE COMPONENT</button>
  <br><br>
  <my-component [onClick]="appOnClick"></my-component>`,
  directives: [MyComponent]
})
export class MyApp { 
  
  public theBoundCallback: Function;
  test:string = "THIS SHOULD HAVE A VALUE";
  
  public ngOnInit(){
    this.theBoundCallback = this.appOnClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  appOnClick(someText){
    
    console.log(someText);
    console.log(this.test);
    
  }
}

bootstrap(MyApp);
```

my-component.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<button (click)="onClick('CLICK FROM COMPONENT')">BUTTOM INSIDE COMPONENT</button>`
})
export class MyComponent{

  @Input() onClick: Function;
  
}
```

That will render two buttons:

BUTTOM OUTSIDE COMPONENT, this calls the appOnClick function direct from the app, when clicked the console shows:
- CLICK FROM APP
- THIS SHOULD HAVE A VALUE

BUTTOM INSIDE COMPONENT, this calls the appOnClick function via the @Input function in the component, when clicked the console shows:
- CLICK FROM APP
- undefined

I've created the example on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UhbcxyJXn3w8SqtU9ysa?p=preview)

Is that a way to assign this correctly so I can work with my object attributes when the callback is trigger?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fpZVN96kSArnf8jm3E63?p=preview)

In order to pass `appOnClick` around this way, you need to declare it as a property like so:

```
export class MyApp {
  ...
  appOnClick = (someText) => {
    console.log(someText);
    console.log(this.test);
  }
}
```

instead of:

```
export class MyApp {
  ...
  appOnClick(someText){
    console.log(someText);
    console.log(this.test);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Mush - no problem :-) if this answer solved the problem, please consider accepting it

Comment: Thanks for this drewmoore, been banging my head why I couldn't access this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot "(...)" when using the appOnClick method and use "[...]" instead of "(...)" when configuring the event handler:

```
<my-component (onClick)="appOnClick($event)"></my-component>`,
```

Moreover within your sub component you need to define a custom event with "@Output":

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<button (click)="handleClick('CLICK FROM COMPONENT')">BUTTOM INSIDE COMPONENT</button>`
})
export class MyComponent{
  @Output()
  onClick:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  handleClick(txt:string) {
    this.onClick.emit(txt);
  }     
}
```